# Angular SSR: Respond to scroll events to set css class

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-ssr

I've added Angular/SSR (v17.1.2) by "ng add" schematic.
Everything started fine, but I need to listen to a scroll event to check the scrollHeight and set a css class on my mat-toolbar. I did this with HostListener before.

I know, that "window" or "document" are not available within server-side-rendering.

Tried to use a check `if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform))` inside HostListener.
Also tried the approach from the [Angular docs](https://angular.dev/guide/ssr#authoring-server-compatible-components).

Nothing worked.
Is there a way?

Comment: "nothing worked" please elaborate

Comment: Sorry, with "nothing worked" I meant nothing from my mentioned attempts worked to solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 17 SSR, this should do the trick. Additionally, NgZone is required to make change available in template. And finally, changeDetectorRef avoids expression changed after check (NG100)

```
  ...
  scrollSub$: any;
  constructor(private z: NgZone, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    afterNextRender(() => {
      this.scrollSub$ = fromEvent(window, 'scroll', { capture: true });
      this.scrollSub$.subscribe(() => {
        this.z.run(() => {
          this.windowScrolled = true;
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        });
      })
    });

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.scrollSub$) {
      this.scrollSub$.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
  const scroll$ = fromEvent(window, 'scroll', { passive: true });
  scroll$.subscribe(
     ... Your code
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried your code inside ngOnInit and constructor and started the dev server by "npm run dev:ssr" (the ng add ssr schematic added this script). But unfortunately it also didn't work. 
I've tried: 
    "if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
      const scroll$ = fromEvent(window, 'scroll', { passive: true });
      scroll$.subscribe(() => {
        return console.log('Scrolled');
      }
      );
    }"

I am not even getting the console log :(

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**